# steema tee chart export to excel data format issue

Tags: activex, teechart

im trying to export series data in excel from teechart editor.
on exporting the excel gets series data as x and y columns in format of two decimal places.
I want is to export data in scientific notation.

I had partial success by providing the format in series tab ->general here i can provide format for the values. But this changes the format for both columns of the series.
what i want is normal default format for x values of the series and scientific format for the Y series in the exported excel.

Please someone guide me how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=74067#p74067):

Since the ValueFormat is a Series property, it is applied to both X and Y ValueLists. The only way around I can think on would be to use a temporal chart splitting each series into two series, one for the X values (with the default ValueFormat) and one for the Y values (with the modified ValueFormat). Ie:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()  
  TChart1.Header.Text.Text = TChart1.Version

  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

  TChart1.AddSeries scLine
  TChart1.AddSeries scLine

  TChart1.Series(0).ValueFormat = "0.######0e-0"
  TChart1.Series(1).ValueFormat = "0.######0e-0"

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To 5
    TChart1.Series(0).AddXY i, Rnd * 100, "", clTeeColor
    TChart1.Series(1).AddXY i, Rnd * 100, "", clTeeColor
  Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim tmpChart
  Set tmpChart = CreateObject("TeeChart.TChart")

  Dim i, y As Integer
  For i = 0 To TChart1.SeriesCount - 1
    tmpChart.AddSeries scPoint
    tmpChart.AddSeries scPoint

    For j = 0 To TChart1.Series(i).Count - 1
      tmpChart.Series(tmpChart.SeriesCount - 2).Add TChart1.Series(i).XValues.Value(j), "", clTeeColor
      tmpChart.Series(tmpChart.SeriesCount - 1).Add TChart1.Series(i).YValues.Value(j), "", clTeeColor
    Next j

    tmpChart.Series(tmpChart.SeriesCount - 2).YValues.Name = "X"
    tmpChart.Series(tmpChart.SeriesCount - 1).ValueFormat = TChart1.Series(i).ValueFormat
  Next i

  TChart1.Export.asXLS.IncludeHeader = True
  TChart1.Export.asXLS.UseSeriesFormat = True


  TChart1.Export.asXLS.SaveToFile "C:\tmp\axtest.xls"
End Sub
```

Worth to note here the export to .xlsx files by code, supporting Excel > 2010, hasn't been implemented yet in TeeChart ActiveX: [#1670](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1670).